# Apt-Cacher for all ubuntu version.. Is it possible.?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-cache, apt-mirror

Presently I have apt-mirror for 10.04,11.04,11.10,12.04 versions of Ubuntu. After reading Apt-Cacher thought of implementing it.

Before doing it, do I need to put apt-cacher for all the above mentioned versions of Ubuntu or I can put one single apt-cacher server and download all the version packages?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

apt-cache can handle multiple different versions of Ubuntu (or other apt based distributions). There is nothing to configure, it just works that way out of the box.